# GPG system call in PHP

Tags: php, gnupg

I need to append my public key (which is in a variable) in **pubring of .gnupg** using the system call in PHP.  What system call is available for this?

```
$gpg = system('gpg --recipient userid --output outfile.asc --armor  --encrypt hello.txt', $retvalue);//calling gpg encrypt command using system call
echo '
Output: ' . $gpg . '
Return value: ' . $retvalue;
```

How can I pass my public key to this GPG encryption command?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is: Which external command to call, or how to call an external command in PHP?

Comment: is there any command/system call() which can put my public key to pubring of .gnupg

Answer (score 1):

Check out PHP manual about the system calls here http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
also look into exec() http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php if you want to open some external program to manage your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the [backtick operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is [gnupg_import()](http://docs.php.net/gnupg_import) function which does just what you need. Otherwise, you will have to resort to command-line and follow [this manual](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap19sec154.html)